# WinSCP .NET assembly: FileMask in Directory Synchronization not working

Tags: c#, winscp, winscp-net

Here is what I want to do in laymen terms first: I want to get files (and maybe some files only). If there are sub-directories, I want to get files in those sub-directories as well. I am using Visual C++/CLI to program, so I am using .net assembly.

In WinSCP, that is to use `Session.SynchronizeDirectories()`. The last parameter is the `TransferOptions` (a class) and it is usually set to null. Basically that means every files will be transferred. If I create an object and set the property `string FileMask`, I should be able to transfer only certain files.

So I change the [WinSCP **C#** example program](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_synchronizedirectories#csharp) to:

```
using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Will continuously report progress of synchronization
    session.FileTransferred += FileTransferred;

    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Create a TransferOptions object
    TransferOptions tro = new TransferOptions();
    tro.FileMask = "*.txt";
    tro.TransferMode = TransferMode.Automatic;

    // Synchronize files
    SynchronizationResult synchronizationResult;
    synchronizationResult =
        session.SynchronizeDirectories(
             SynchronizationMode.Local, @"C:\temp\win", "/C/Users/peter/Documents/WinSCP5.5.1/",
             false, false, SynchronizationCriteria.Time, tro);

    // Throw on any error
    synchronizationResult.Check();
}
```

When I run the program, **everything** in the current directory and sub-directories are transferred!

Thinking I may be wrong in the specifying those options. I use the WinSCP program. (Can refer to picture in WinSCP web site [Transfer Settings Dialog](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_transfer_custom) page.)

All options are clear except I enter the following for the File mask:
`*.txt`

I click OK button to begin transfer. I have the preview option on. **And I see only txt files selected, even the one in the sub-directories**.

So WinSCP program works, but not the API?

[Edit] I am using version 5.5.2 of WinSCP assembly.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Your code looks good. Please set `Session.SessionLogPath` and share the log. For example using pastebin.com.

Comment: Here is the log and it is in http://pastebin.com/xR27KwBH

Comment: The log does not match your code. The log uses binary transfer mode, while your code sets automatic. The log shows that orphan files are deleted, while you pass `false` to `delete` parameter in the code. There are different paths too. It's difficult to help you, if you do not share matching log and code.

Comment: I look at the log and it seems the assembly is calling the script in return. Anyway, from the log, it does not seem like there is any filtering at all!

And to answer your question, for security problem, I have modified the path before posting. I will modify the original posts.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/g7e6BvtT
I run the program again. Even if I make sure the transfer mode as Automatic, it still transfers as Binary. The two false inside `SynchronizeDirectories` are : no delete and no mirror.

Comment: Even if I use ASCII mode, the session log still says Binary! And if the mask is *.*>100K, **every files** are transferred. Again, I am using 5.5.2 version.

Comment: I have tried your EXACT code and it WORKS as expected. The call to Session.SynchronizeDirectories gets correctly translated to `synchronize local   -nopermissions -preservetime -transfer="automatic" -filemask="*.txt" -criteria="time" -- "C:\temp\win" "/C/Users/peter/Documents/WinSCP5.5.1/"`

Comment: Actually the behavior seen in your logs it as if you do not pass the `TransferOptions` instance at all (binary mode is default as well as empty file mask obviously). Are you sure the logs are from the EXACT! code you have included in the question?

Comment: O my! I will then have to check everything again. Including getting the version5.5.2 again or whatever the latest version. Hum... Why so many problems for me.

Comment: I suggest you to download source code of WinSCP .NET assembly and compile it on your own, so that you can debug translation from `Session.SynchronizeDirectories` to underlying script command.

Comment: I include the source code project into my existing project. Compile the source code project. In my existing project, I 'add reference' to the DLL compiled. Run it. Only the TXT files are transferred! Good. I then remove the project. Use back the EXE (from Winscp552.zip with File Version as 5.5.2.4130) and DLL (from Winscp5552automation.zip with File Version as 1.1.5.4130). Somehow when I start the program, it takes 30 seconds to reach the first statement! One thing to note is the compiled DLL has File Version as 1.1.5.0!

Comment: But does it work after you return to the official build? (30s delay is another topic)

Comment: Yes. It works. After further testing, for all 3 versions (5.5.1, 5.5.2 and 5.5.3), if I use EXE and DLL, there is 30s delay. Say I use the 5.5.3 EXE and compile the source for DLL, there is no 30s delay. I guess I will type in as solution.

Comment: So do you know what was the problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close the question. It seems that you can no longer reproduce the problem. Neither I can.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get it working before Easter holiday. After working with @Martin for sometime, I pass through the problem. (Note that I am not saying I have found out the solution.) :(

Anyway, I download the source code for WinSCP 5.5.2 version. I have to modify the project from dot net version 4 back to version 3.5 as I am using Visual Studio 2008. I include it in my original project. Compile it. OK. I have the original project to use that output DLL. I make sure the WinSCP EXE is also verison 5.5.2. Run it. No problem. File mask is working.

Just a side story if you are interested. After using the source code project, I remove it. I use back the 5.5.2 DLL downloaded from website. Suddenly the program needs 30s or so to execute the first statement. I then use version 5.5.1 EXE and DLL. Same delay. Switch to 5.5.3 EXE and DLL. Same 30s or so delay. Remove the DLL and use 5.5.3 .net assembly source code. Compile it. Program runs immediately.

I guess from now on I will compile my .net assembly and use it.

Thanks Martin for help.